# How to limit the scope of a variable to the function when declared in an If statement

Tags: vb.net, scope

I need to limit the scope of a variable to the function it resides with however I need to declare it within an if statement as it's type will change depending. I'm working within VB.NET

```
Public Function CourseDataTable()
    If RadioCourses.Checked Then
        Dim SearchBy As New classSearchCourses
    ElseIf RadioAttendees.Checked Then
        Dim SearchBy As New classSearchAttendees
    End If
```

The obvious problem is that the variable doesn't persist outside of the if statement. I want to limit the scope of this variable because a, it's used else where and b, memory leakage, the class could very well end up holding whole SQL tables and I don't want that persisting when it's not needed.
I can't use inheritance or polymorph here because I'm working a legacy system.

This is probably a rework (I'm struggling think of a different way of approaching it evidently) as I can't find anything in MSDN that allows procedure scope but ignores any other blocks at declaration.

Comment: If this variable is only going to exist in this function, then just make a new variable and properly dispose of it when you are done with it.

Comment: Does you class inherit (or implement) from any common one?

Comment: It might be simpler to have 2 different functions entirely rather than numerous, long IF blocks to do this.  Your *a* and *b* points are more about how it is coded than where/how vars are declared.

Comment: @Plutonix There are only three if blocks for this however the actual function is over 200 lines long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is still possible to use polymorphism in a legacy system.  What you can do is find the common functionality that must exist between the two in order for you to even want to reuse the same variable.  Then you can create wrapper classes for each of these legacy classes.  The wrapper class would implement the common interface and simply call the underlying legacy implementation.  Then you simply declare a variable to that common Interface and create the appropriate wrapper class instance inside of the if statements.

**Edit:**  If you have the ability to modify the legacy classes at all, a simpler solution would be to simply create a common Interface that both of the legacy classes can implement.  This will give you the polymorphic functionality that you desire without the need of wrapper classes.  VB.Net even provides the ability to implement an interface in a way to where the interface methods are only exposed by a Interface reference.  To do this, you simply mark the interface implementation methods as Private.

Comment: Good answer however the other is preferable because it only adds one line and requires little thought. I'll definitely look into this further though.

Comment: Yes, the other answer definitely works, but I tend to lean more on the type system instead of resorting to Object references.  To use an Object reference, you would either need Option Strict Off (not recommended), or you will have to do runtime type checks and casts.  Adding the common interface moves the type checks to compile time so you can be more confident in the code.  It also allows you to reuse the interface in other places without doing the same type checks.

Answer (score 2):

You could just declare `SearchBy` as `Object` and then do something like this

```
        Dim searchBy As Object
        If RadioCourses.Checked Then
            searchBy = New classSearchCourses
        ElseIf RadioAttendees.Checked Then
            searchBy = New classSearchAttendees
        End If

        If searchBy.GetType() Is GetType(classSearchCourses) Then
            'Do something
        ElseIf searchBy.GetType() Is GetType(classSearchAttendees) Then
            'Do something else
        End If
```

This is still inheritance though since most everything inherits from System.Object but it will save you declaring your own new base class if for some reason you can't do that

Comment: I believe that the following also works.
If TypeOf searchBy Is classSearchCourses.

Comment: Yeah, that should work as well @Scott and is actually a bit more readable :)